# Syntactic order

Tags: sentence-structure

Wann war das letzte Mal, dass du dich gezwungen gefühlt hast, etwas zu tun?

I'd like to know if that is how you would write the sentence 'When was the last time that you felt compelled to do something?'

Comment: Please read the above.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it this way, the order is correct. But there are simpler alternatives:

> Wann hast du dich zuletzt gezwungen gefühlt, etwas zu tun?
>
> Wann zuletzt hast du dich gezwungen gefühlt, etwas zu tun?

Or with imperfect tense:

> Wann war es zuletzt, dass du dich gezwungen fühltest, etwas zu tun?
>
> Wann war es, dass du dich zuletzt gezwungen fühltest, etwas zu tun?

Comment: *Sich gezwungen sehen* is probably more common than *sich gezwungen fühlen*. But the question is about word order.

Comment: @tofro: Auf alle Fälle eine echte Alternative.